# Secure Local Code Repository vs Remote Development

Tags: remote-desktop, source-code, versioning

I am working with one of my business partner for developing applications for them. I am working in overseas and partner resides in USA. Partner wants to provide me Remote Desktop access to work on their code base. I am little bit concerned about the performance of remote desktop session. So I requested the partner to download or upload code base from my local machine using some secure communication. But client concerned over code being in local machine due to exposure out side of the company. Is there technology that is available that protects the partner code base and at the same time gives developer performance at most same speed as working local machine. By the way I am working in .Net and Windows 7 or 8.

Comment: The title of this question really needs an overhaul, but I can't think of a better alternative to suggest off the top of my head.

Comment: Also, I can't help but wonder: once you're in via RDP, what's to stop you, or a malicious process running on your system, from copying anything and everything you/it wants to to your local system or beyond? I'm getting the feeling that the root issue may be deeper than simply where the files are stored, and if you address that, maybe the client's concerns will be resolved as well.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I took a stab at refining the title to "Secure Local Code Repository vs Remote Development"

Comment: @AthomSfere That does sound better. Unfortunately I don't have the rep to have a real say in the matter.